# Change Button color on every Click [ Javascript ]

Tags: javascript, html

I try to write a simple program to change color of a divs in a container every  time i click..  on the first click  it only changes color to on Div 1 ,Div 3,Div 5. on the second click  it does Vice versa,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>clciks</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div>This is Div 1</div>
    <div>This is Div 2</div>
    <div>This is Div 3</div>
    <div>This is Div 4</div>
    <div>This is Div 5</div>
  </div>
  <script>
    let x = document.getElementById("container");
    let y = x.children;
    let click = 0;

    function myFunction() {
      for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        y[i].onclick = function() {
          if (click == 0) {
            y[i].style.color = "blue";
            click = 1;
          } else {
            y[i].style.color = "red";
            click = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    myFunction();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You wan these to change independently of each other? Right now, they all share the `click` variable.

Comment: Could you be a little clearer? Maybe edit your question, I can't follow

Comment: Mr Iraklis and Mr Tolumide on the first click i want each div to change color to blue then on the second click i want each div to change color to red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to change the `onClick` function a bit inside...

Hope this helps...

```js
let x = document.getElementById("container");
    let y = x.children;
    let click = 0;
    function changeColorForEach(){
    for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      if(y[i].style.color === "blue"){
                y[i].style.color = "red";
            }else{
                y[i].style.color = "blue";
            }
      }
    }
    function myFunction() {
      for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        y[i].onclick = changeColorForEach;
      }
    }
    myFunction();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>clciks</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div>This is Div 1</div>
    <div>This is Div 2</div>
    <div>This is Div 3</div>
    <div>This is Div 4</div>
    <div>This is Div 5</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How can we achieve it by using Javascript Class?

Comment: we can create 2 classes `.blue` and `.red` and toggle the `classlist` for each of the element...

Comment: I mean't Javascript Object Oriented

Answer (score 1):

They are sharing the same `click` variable.
Just put your `let click = 0;` inside the `for` in each `div`

> **@GoodnessGoodness Chi:**
>  Can we do a little modification from your
>   answer?
> Now i wan't to change the color of All DIVS to yellow when the div return `nodeType == 1` is cliked

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <title>clciks</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="container">
        <div>This is Div 1</div>
        <div>This is Div 2</div>
        <div>This is Div 3</div>
        <div>This is Div 4</div>
        <div>This is Div 5</div>
      </div>
      <script>
        let x = document.getElementById("container");
        let y = x.children;
        

        function myFunction() {
          for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            let click = 0;
            let z = x.childNodes;
            y[i].onclick = function() {
              if (click == 0) {
                y[i].style.color = "blue";
                click = 1;
              } else {
                y[i].style.color = "red";
                click = 0;
              }
//now change the color of DIVS to yellow
            if(z[i].nodeType == 1)
{
y[i].style.color = "yellow";
}
            }
          }
        }
        myFunction();
      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can control css without any loops

the **simplest code** using **click** event

```js
$("#container").on("click",
  function(e) {
    if (e.target.style.color === "red") {
        e.target.style.color = "blue"
        return;
      }
      e.target.style.color = "red"
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>clciks</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div>This is Div 1</div>
    <div>This is Div 2</div>
    <div>This is Div 3</div>
    <div>This is Div 4</div>
    <div>This is Div 5</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```